# flex container min-height ignored in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

As far as I've been able to gather, if working with IE10 / IE11 I should be able to use the standardized flex terms.

I have a container div and 2 child divs.

The 2 child divs are not larger than 400px, so there should always be enough room for the `justify-content: space-between`.

I want the first child to be all the way at the top and the second child to be all the way at the bottom.

This works in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE, and I have no idea why.

Any comments and feedback are welcome.

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: space-between; min-height: 400px; background-color: lightyellow;">
  <div style="background-color: red;">
    <h2>Title (variable height)</h2>
    <p>Summary (variable height)</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: orange;">
    <img src="http://avatarbox.net/avatars/img32/tv_test_card_avatar_picture_61484.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/akxn68vm/

Comment: I've added a background color for the container. ( yellow ). You can see on the jsFiddle that the container is 400px in IE.

Comment: as @GCyrillus said `min-height` in IE with flex and `flex-direction: column` don't works properly, use `height` instead

Answer (score 31, accepted):

IE 10 & 11 have a number of issues with rendering flexbox properly.

Here's one: A flex container doesn't respect  the `min-height` property in these browsers.

A simple solution is to make your flex container also a flex item.

Just add this to your code (no other changes necessary):

```
body {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}
```

[revised fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akxn68vm/4/)

More info: https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-3

Comment: thanks for the solutions. Even the min-height property is outside the bugged flex container, this solution works as soon as you add this to the element with the min-height

Answer (score 5):

According to [this bug](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/101487/) IE11 doesn't render the items correctly when using min-height in flexbox.

It seems like the problem was solved in Edge, but IE10-11 will not work.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in IE10/11. You can find the information at https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-3

To fix this bug in IE10/11, add a wrapper element around the flex container that is itself a flex container. In your example, you can add display flex to body tag. And  add width 100% style in the container div