# Can't get display:block element (instead a display:flex element) to contain it's child in IE11

Tags: css, html, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

How can I get my block element to contain it's child in IE11 EDGE?

In the fiddle, you can see that `<footer>` is sitting below `<login-page>` when it should be sitting below `<login>`. (Because `<login-page>` isn't encapsulating `<login>`).

Works fine in Chrome, not IE11.

https://jsfiddle.net/10ohr6wy/1/

Would love to get some advice on this thanks. Ideally a non-obtrusive fix would be preferred, as have legacy constraints.

Comment: May be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845011/are-custom-elements-valid-html5 Note that it says custom elements must contain a `-` in the tag name. Also, a link to support shows that it's spotty: http://caniuse.com/#feat=custom-elements When you have support like that, you're guaranteed to end up with inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: Interesting read, thanks.

Comment: The answer to your other question is: Instead of `flex: 1` use `flex: 1 1 auto`. Here are the details: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32239549/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are actually dealing with the `flex` + `min-height` bug.

One way, to go over it, is to set the parent as a `flex` `column` element:

here

```
body {
display:flex;
flex-flow:column;
}
```

works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/10ohr6wy/3/

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
app {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.xui-page-body {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}
login-page {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: -40px;
  display: block;
  background: green;
}
login {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
footer {
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<app>
  <div class="xui-page-body">
    <login-page>
      <login></login>
    </login-page>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</app>
```

if you do not set `flex-direction` to `column`, then `app` needs to be the **only child**.

it can be sized via :

- `flex:1;` if you want to include `margin`s

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}
app {
  flex:1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.xui-page-body {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}
login-page {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: -40px;
  display: block;
  background: green;
}
login {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
footer {
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<app>
  <div class="xui-page-body">
    <login-page>
      <login></login>
    </login-page>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</app>
```

or

- `width:100%;` and `box-sizing:border-box` to include `border` and `padding` if any.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}
app {
  width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding: 3em;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.xui-page-body {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}
login-page {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: -40px;
  display: block;
  background: green;
}
login {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
footer {
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<app>
  <div class="xui-page-body">
    <login-page>
      <login></login>
    </login-page>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</app>
```

Comment: I have ran into the next issue. <login> now overhangs the <footer> if the content is long enough. How can I get around this issue? (https://jsfiddle.net/10ohr6wy/8/)

Comment: @Baconbeastnz you need to apply also `flex: 1 1 auto;` to `.xui-page-body` as well for IE. https://jsfiddle.net/10ohr6wy/9/

Answer (score 1):

Make the `body` element a flex container.

Give `app` full width.

[**revised fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/10ohr6wy/4/)

```css
body {
  display: flex; /* new */
}

app {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%; /* new */
}
.xui-page-body {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
}
login-page {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: -40px;
  display: block;
  background:green;
}
login {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
footer {
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  background:black;
}
```

```html
<app>
  <div class="xui-page-body">
    <login-page>
      <login></login>
    </login-page>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</app>
```

Also see: [flex container min-height ignored in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40490954/3597276)