# Vertical align (Bootstrap 3) elements in flexbox container in IE10+11

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have an issue with IE10+11 when vertically centering two Bootstrap columns in a row using flexbox.

The columns have dynamic content and the row must have a min-height of 65px. However, if the content expands into several lines of text, the row should be able to grow in height - still maintaining the columns vertically aligned. Hence, specifying a fixed height isn't an option.

The problem is that in IE10+11 flexbox only works with a specific height - not min-height.

I tried with display table-cell, float: none, etc. but it breaks the column offset in Bootstrap.

Does anyone know a workaround for this issue?

The html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-9 col-xs-offset-4 col-sm-offset-3">Title - I can be any size</div>
  <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-9 col-xs-offset-4 col-sm-offset-3">Optional sub title - I can be any size</div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.row {
  min-height: 65px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

[JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/6qp5tzav/1/) (including vendor prefixes.)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40490954/3597276

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the min-height bug can we workedaround by wrapping the `.row` in an element with another flex definition - like this:

```
<div class="row-fix">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-9 col-xs-offset-4 col-sm-offset-3">Title - I can be any size</div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-9 col-xs-offset-4 col-sm-offset-3">Optional sub title - I can be any size</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

adding this to css:

```
.row-fix {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
 }
.row {
    min-height: 65px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
```