# Flexbox max-height issue with IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to code a search menu separated in three parts. Each part will have a scrollbar if there's not enough vertical space for the results to display.

In Chrome and Firefox, each menu displays its scrollbar, but on IE11, the menus overlap the wrapper.

I've coded a sample which works on Chrome and Firefox (Firefox was tricky, I needed to add `overflow: hidden` on multiple levels of the menu).

```css
.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 1184px;
  max-height: 80vh;
  border: 2px solid red;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.flex-wrapper .flex-wrapper-inner {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-wrapper .flex-wrapper-inner .header {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-wrapper .flex-wrapper-inner .header H4 {
  flex: 1;
}

.flex-wrapper .flex-wrapper-inner .column-wrapper {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-wrapper .flex-wrapper-inner .column {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.flex-wrapper .flex-wrapper-inner .column H4 {
  text-align: center;
}

.box-results-users .list-group-item {
  margin: 0;
}

.box-results-users .list-group-item IMG {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}

.box-results {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="flex-wrapper">
  <div class="flex-wrapper-inner">
    <div class="header">
      <h4>Box 1</h4>
      <h4>Box 2</h4>
      <h4>Box 3</h4>

    </div>
    <div class="column-wrapper">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="box-results list-group">
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>


        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="box-results">
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="box-results box-results-users">
          <div class="media list-group-item">
            <div class="media-left">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/38.jpg" alt="...">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">User Test</h4>
              ...
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="media list-group-item">
            <div class="media-left">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/38.jpg" alt="...">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">User Test</h4>
              ...
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="media list-group-item">
            <div class="media-left">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/38.jpg" alt="...">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">User Test</h4>
              ...
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="media list-group-item">
            <div class="media-left">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/38.jpg" alt="...">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">User Test</h4>
              ...
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="media list-group-item">
            <div class="media-left">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/38.jpg" alt="...">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">User Test</h4>
              ...
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="media list-group-item">
            <div class="media-left">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/38.jpg" alt="...">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">User Test</h4>
              ...
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="media list-group-item">
            <div class="media-left">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/38.jpg" alt="...">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">User Test</h4>
              ...
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="media list-group-item">
            <div class="media-left">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/38.jpg" alt="...">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">User Test</h4>
              ...
            </div>
          </div>





        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Am I missing something on IE 11 ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have two problems to address in this layout for it to work in Chrome, Safari, Firefox and IE11.

#### The minimum sizing algorithm on flex items.

A flex item, by default, cannot be smaller than the size of its content. The minimum size is defined in the spec as `min-width: auto` and `min-height: auto`.

Some browsers take it upon themselves to adjust this setting (which is why your layout works in Chrome). Other browsers require you to override the default setting (which is what is needed in FF and IE11).

You can override the default with `min-width: 0` / `min-height: 0`, or `overflow` with any value other than `visible`.

Add this to your code:

```
.flex-wrapper .flex-wrapper-inner .column-wrapper {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;; /* IE11 & Firefox fix */
}
```

Here's a more complete explanation:

- [Why doesn't flex item shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)

---

#### IE11 is ignoring the `max-height` and `min-height` on your flex container.

In your layout, it appears that IE11 is simply ignoring your `max-height` and `min-height` rules. However, these rules appear to work fine on flex items. So make your container also a flex item.

Add this to your code:

```
body {
  display: flex; /* IE11 fix */
}
```

More information:

- [flex container min-height ignored in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40490954/flex-container-min-height-ignored-in-ie)
- https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs

---

```css
body {
  display: flex; /* IE11 fix */
}

.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 1184px;
  max-height: 80vh;
  border: 2px solid red;
  smin-height: 150px;
  flex-shrink: 0; /* override default `flex-shrink: 1` */
}

.flex-wrapper .flex-wrapper-inner {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-wrapper .flex-wrapper-inner .header {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-wrapper .flex-wrapper-inner .header H4 {
  flex: 1;
}

.flex-wrapper .flex-wrapper-inner .column-wrapper {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;; /* IE11 & Firefox fix */
}

.flex-wrapper .flex-wrapper-inner .column {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.flex-wrapper .flex-wrapper-inner .column H4 {
  text-align: center;
}

.box-results-users .list-group-item {
  margin: 0;
}

.box-results-users .list-group-item IMG {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}

.box-results {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="flex-wrapper">
  <div class="flex-wrapper-inner">
    <div class="header">
      <h4>Box 1</h4>
      <h4>Box 2</h4>
      <h4>Box 3</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="column-wrapper">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="box-results list-group">
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>


        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="box-results">
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>
          <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Quisque coeptis possedit radiis. Ardentior et contraria et quinta feras</a>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="box-results box-results-users">
          <div class="media list-group-item">
            <div class="media-left">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/38.jpg" alt="...">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">User Test</h4> ...
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="media list-group-item">
            <div class="media-left">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/38.jpg" alt="...">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">User Test</h4> ...
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="media list-group-item">
            <div class="media-left">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/38.jpg" alt="...">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">User Test</h4> ...
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="media list-group-item">
            <div class="media-left">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/38.jpg" alt="...">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">User Test</h4> ...
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="media list-group-item">
            <div class="media-left">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/38.jpg" alt="...">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">User Test</h4> ...
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="media list-group-item">
            <div class="media-left">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/38.jpg" alt="...">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">User Test</h4> ...
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="media list-group-item">
            <div class="media-left">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/38.jpg" alt="...">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">User Test</h4> ...
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="media list-group-item">
            <div class="media-left">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/38.jpg" alt="...">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">User Test</h4> ...
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o0uk6etv/5/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! In my case I cannot use display: flex on the body since this component is a part of a bigger website, and using flexbox on the body would maybe cause other issues.

I'm going to try to compute height with javascript on IE 11. I'll keep this subject in touch with my tests.

Comment: I only used `body` in the demo because it's the parent in this case. In your actual code, you need to apply `display: flex` to the parent of the flex container having `min / max` / `height`, whatever element that may be.