# Setting min-height in grid container in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, css-grid

I'm trying to set

```
display: -ms-grid;
min-height:##px;
height:auto;
```

It seems IE doesn't support min-height in CSS Grid.

Is there any alternative way for achieving the same thing?

Thanks in advance. ❤️

Comment: Probably the same bug that exists in flexbox: [flex container `min-height` ignored in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40490954/3597276)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that IE has a `min-height` bug when using CSS Grid. We can use css-tricks to fix it in IE. You could give the parent a grid column container like below:

```
display: -ms-grid;
-ms-grid-columns: 100%;
```

Then the `min-height` property will work in IE.

Comment: Also display:-ms-flexbox for the parent container worked like a charm